# why html5 video tag goes full screen on play on mobile?

Tags: html, video

I have got a very banal problem but can't find the solution. When I simply play a video with the HTML5 video tag it works perfectly on desktop, but on mobile when user plays the video it goes full screen immediately. The mobile user just clicks the play button and the video goes full screen.

This is the html tags I'm using:

```
<h1>video 1</h1>
<video width="600" height="450" controls>
  <source src="files/prova.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I'm asking you for a solution about this, how can we avoid video going full screen on play on mobile? All answers are welcome.

P.S.: The video is mp4 with H. 264 AAC codec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm here because I found the solution. You only need to add the "playsinline" attribute to your video tag.

Like this:

```
<video autoplay playsinline controls>
```